# Why I can't restart activity launched with REORDER_TO_FRONT flag?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using this code to restart my activity:

```
public void refreshActivity()
{
    final Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    this.finish();

    this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

It works just fine. But if my current Activity was launched with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, it will not start.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13383025/351533):  but I think this is not my case, since I don't relaunch current activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

**UPDATE:**
I can restart my activity, by explicitly telling activity's name, like this:

```
    this.finish();

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

but I need access to my intent to get all his parameters (which are needed to properly load activity).

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag before calling `startActivity()`. Like this:

```
final Intent intent = this.getIntent();
intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() & ~Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
this.finish();

this.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
this.startActivity(intent);
```