# Notification click behaviors depending on the state of the app

Tags: android, android-intent

After a long search, I was not able to find exactly what I need.

I simply want : When a notification is displayed to the user, if the app is simply in background I want to reopen MainActivity. But if the app/activity has been killed, I want to restart the app completely.

My actual code :

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(notification.getSubject())
                        .setContentText(notification.getMessage())
                        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class)
                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notif = mBuilder.build();
        notif.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Case which is not working actually is to restart the app if app or activity has been killed.

EDIT : By killed I mean the app has been closed in the app manager. Or we lost the focus and the activity is destroyed. In those cases I would like to fully restart the app.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't understand why people vote this down. This should normally work. That is: when the notification is shown, and the application dies then the activity (and thus the app) will be restarted automatically. Your confusion might exist because the application will not restart if it is still cached in memory. Then only the activity will be restarted. Is that your problem ?

Comment: About the downvotes: I completely agree with @Werner Van Belle. And please explain in what manner the app has been killed: force-stopped? Swiped from recent apps? Or just lost focus and was destroyed at some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't entirely understand how android functions. Whenever your program is needed, the program is started by android (See the Application class for an onCreate that you can override).

Whenever an activity is necessary it is (re)created or brought to the foreground.

That means that an activity restart does not necessarily imply a restart of the application. In practice, if the program was still in memory, then an application restart won't happen.

If you want to investigate this further

1. create an Application.onCreate method so you see whether your app is restarted or not.
2. trigger the notification
3. go to the android settings, application tab, and there select 'show cached processes'. Clear your process from the list.
4. tap the notification.

This should trigger a restart of the application. If this is indeed the problem then you cannot 'solve' it. Android decides when it will kill your application and when it removes it from memory.

The best solution then is to redesign your activity that whatever the application restart would trigger is also performed in the activity itself. Or so, without more detail what functionality you would like to see performed on an 'activity/application-restart' it is difficult to advice further on this matter.

Comment: Yes that what I was thinking, I just asked to know if there is a workaround around this. In our case that starter activity fetch the user profil on start. Thank's for the precisions

Comment: No problem, I had such a hard time to come to terms with this when I wrote for android. Sometimes an 'old' state of a previous run would pop up and various static variables would already been set while I was expecting them not to... Only after I figure the above out did I understand what was happening.

Comment: yep... When you see the sweet schema of the android lifecycle you just think "ok I just have to do the things in the right order". Then your app grow and it become a mess

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` value to `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)`.

> The reason is due to the way that FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
>   works. When you use this flag, Android looks for an instance of the
>   desired activity in your activity stack, starting from the front of
>   the stack and scanning until it gets to the root/back of the stack. As
>   soon as it finds an instance of the specified activity, it brings that
>   one to the front (ie: if there are multiple instances of the specified
>   activity it will bring to the front the most recent instance).

Original I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964188/bring-an-activity-to-front-using-flag-activity-reorder-to-front). 
See android developer doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT).

I hope its help you.