# How to detect if a parent activity is in the back stack and can go up without creating a new instance?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

I have a system which has several `Activity`, `Activity X`, `Activity A`, `Activity B`, and `Activity Y`. `Activity X` consist of list of `A`. If we click on `A`, it will go to `Activity A`. `Activity A` consist of list of `B`. If we click on `B`, it will go to `Activity B`. `Activity B` will also consist of list of `B`. So, if we click `B` on `Activity B`, it will go to `Activity B`. It is possible to end up the stack like this: `X -> A -> B -> B -> B -> B -> B`. According to proper navigation by Android, if we click `Up` on `Activity B`, it should go to `Activity A`, no matter how deep the stack is. So, every `B` on the previous stack should end up on `A`. Up until now, it's simple. I just need to set the parent class of `Activity B` as `Activity A`.

The problem is I can go to `Activity B` from `Activity Y`. If I open the `Activity B` from `Activity Y`, this `Activity B` is not always know how to open `Activity A` because the parent of `B` can be another `B` or `A`. `B` only know his parent. The problem is how to detect that `Activity A` is reachable automatically without creating a new instance from `Activity B`? This way, I can make my code like the following on `Activity B`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (canGoUpToActivityA()) { // this means this Activity B is opened from Activity A directly (A -> B) or indirectly (A -> B -> ... -> B), not from Activity Y
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            } else {
                Intent intent;

                if (TYPE_B.equals(mParent.getType())) {
                   intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
                } else {
                   intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
                }

                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, mParent)
                startActivity(intent);                    

                return true;
            }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If anybody down voting me because they think the solution is as simple as `singleTop` to `Activity A`, that's mean you guys don't understand my problem. See the last sentence of my first paragraph. I don't have any problem with going up from `Activity B` to `Activity A`, no matter how deep it is if `Activity B` is opened from `Activity A`.

Without the above `onOptionsItemSelected`, I can go up to `Activity A` from `Activity B` if `Activity B` is opened from `Activity A` directly `(A -> B)` or indirectly `(A -> B -> ... -> B)`. This is not my problem.

The problem comes when I opened `Activity B` from `Activity Y`. I can't just go back to `Activity A` because `Activity A` rely on information from `Activity X`. If I open `Activity B` from `Activity Y`, then I go up, I should go to the parent of `Activity B`, where it can be `A` or another `B`.

The above code without `canGoUpToActivityA()` part will solve my problem. With that code, when I open `Activity B` from `Activity Y`, then going up should always go to the parent of `B`. That's already correct (`B` only know its parent, which can be not `A`).

But, when I open `Activity B` from `Activity A`, then I go up, it will launch the parent of `Activity B`. If I open `Activity B` from `Activity A` directly (A -> B), it's is indeed what I want. But, when I open `Activity B` from another `Activity B` (A-> B -> ... -> B), that's the problem. Because I should go up to `Activity A`, not the parent of `Activity B` which can be another `Activity B`.

Comment: Why not this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13383025/2700586?

Comment: I got a feeling you haven't read about launch modes: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I've put `singleTop` for `Activity A`

Comment: That should resolve your issue of having Activity B with another Activity B as a parent then.

Comment: @Mani It's different case

Comment: @AllanW, I never say I have a problem with that. The problem comes when I open `Activity B` from `Activity Y`, where in this case `Activity B` cannot open `Activity A` directly since `Activity B` don't know how to open `Activity A`. `Activity B` is also don't come from `Activity A`, but `Activity Y`.

Comment: You mentioned not knowing about the parent in the question and gave that as an example. If you always want `activity B` to launch `activity A` when pressing back, why not just launch an intent to `activity A`? It won't matter what's in the back stack then. And you can use the links above to allow activities that are in the backstack to be moved to the top rather than recreated and positioned twice.

Comment: @AllanW Yes, `Activity B` only know its own parent. If all the parent of `B` is always `A`, i can open `Activity A` with intent. But, the problem is the parent of `B` can be `A` or another `B`. I need to have conditional check for this one to open `Activity A` if the parent is `A` or to open `Activity B` if the parent is `B`. I've solved this one with the above code without `canGoUpToActivityA()` part. But, that means from `Activity B`, I always go to the parent of `B`, where it can be another `B`. If I open it from `Activity Y`, that's what I want. But, if I open it from `Activity A` it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not clear on what exactly you want, so I'll break this up into snippets:

If you want to launch a parent of `Activity B` and ensure that it isn't "launching itself", you can use the `singleTop` flag as noted by others to ensure that only one instance of `B` is ever on the top. You mentioned you don't have an issue with that, but you've listed that as an example, so just keep that in mind.

You've also mentioned that you check if the parent is `A` before launching `Activity A`. If all you want to do is actually launch the previous activity in the stack, there is no need for an Intent. Just finish your activity and it will exit the stack, showing the previous activity.

If you have a set activity that you should launch when going back, you can simply launch it with an intent. At this point, it doesn't matter what the previous activity is, because you are explicitly starting an activity for a given class. Again, you may look at the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039189/intent-if-activity-is-running-bring-it-to-front-else-start-a-new-one-from-n) flag to ensure that an existing activity is not recreated.

Lastly, if you have some complex logic that requires you to know the full stack history, you can always pass data through your bundle. A simple example is an arraylist of the simple class name so you know everything in the current task.

---

Edit: Since you've also added that you depend on information from previous classes, I take it that you need more than just the class name.

Note that you can always pass data through the bundles so that they are retained through all subsequent activities. You can also pass all the current data by calling [putExtras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)).

And if your entire flow is geared towards going to a child and then passing data back to a parent, consider using [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)). That way, you can set result codes and data and finish your activity to directly pass information to the previous activity, without launching a new intent in a forward flow manner.

Comment: I ended up with the solution in your last paragraph.

Comment: @Sam I have updated my answer since you mentioned that activities actually depend on data in other activities. This implies you'll need to know more than just which activities are in the stack.